# Tk.filedialog scroll by mouse wheel

Tags: tkinter, horizontal-scrolling, filedialog

How can I activate scrolling by the **mouse wheel** when Tk.filedialog.askopenfilename displays LOTs of files.

Comment: I don't think you can. As far as I know Tcl calls os native dialog screen here.

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: I'm using Linux. Python's Tk.filedialog.askopenfilename is wrapper of

Comment: Perhaps provide a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://coderwall.com/p/xnez3g/horizontal-scroll-with-mouse-under-linux) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to use  <kbd>Shift + Mouse Wheel</kbd>  for scrolling horizontally.

For Windows 7 there's only either one of horizontal or vertical scrollbar present by default, and regular <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd> scrolling can be used in both cases as there's only one present at a time.

Comment: Sorry, as is,  this doesn't work for me - or do I have to configure the filedialog?

Comment: @HJarausch Sorry I've typed `Space` instead of `Shift` earlier.